# Why does React Native linking lead to workspace integrity error?

Tags: xcode, react-native, npm, react-native-ios, react-native-native-ui-component

I have troubles with the development of a React Native app.

I have developed a native module and a native ui component.

Finally, I would like to publish both as a NPM module.

However, when I tried to integrate the native module and the native ui as NPM package into a (new) React Native app (for example created with `react-native init` command), I first got the following error `Invariant Violation requireNativeComponent ComponentName was not found in UIManager`. According to some GitHub issues this might be a problem with missing linking.

So I decided to run `react-native link`. However, by doing this the situation got even worse, because from that point on I got the following error `Workspace Integrity Error - Couldn't load project` for all the RCT libraries.

[image: Error messages]

I already followed the instructions of other Stackoverflow posts regarding that topic, which describe how to investigate the `.pbxproj` file. Further, I tried to reinstall the pods of my npm package. Finally, I ensured that I use the `.xcworkspace` file and not the `.xcodeproj` file.

However, the errors still persist.

Comment: `react-native link` and cocoapods don’t play nicely together. If you need to stick with cocoapods you ought to bring RN libraries as subspecs via your Podfile instead..

Comment: @RobHogan I will try this, although I had had some troubles in the past with that approach too.

Comment: If you want to try it that way and post your podfile we can see if we can spot any issues. You’ll need to revert the `link` though.

Comment: @RobHogan if I revert the linking I again get `Invariant Violation requireNativeComponent ComponentName was not found in UIManager`. Do you know anything to do about that?

Comment: That's expected if nothing's linked. Instead of using `react-native link` though, setting up your `Podfile` as in http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps#configuring-cocoapods-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me by

- opening a new .xcworkspace file
- clean project
- Pressing on "Build and run the current scheme"